# If there are any discernible effects of travelling through curved space..?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

If one is on a spaceship traveling through a 'very' curved section of space-time, are there experiments one could perform on the ship that would reveal measurable differences between the very curved space and the 'usual flat' space one experiences 'around' the Earth? Note, any straight ruler on the ship would still seem straight relative to a person on the ship. Would laser beams be distorted?

Comment: Is one following a geodesic?

Comment: I'm not sure? Would any discernible distortions be greater perpendicular to a geodesic?

Comment: Well, the equivalence principle should still hold, but beyond that, yes. Not being on a geodesic *could* feel very different from normal flat space.

Comment: When you say distortions, that makes me worried. Curved space due to gravity does not mean space is actually curving around such that a ruler would look bent and warped.

Comment: if the curvature was great enough would there not be a measurable acceleration?

Comment: I should have said traveling through curved space without any acceleration.

Comment: @Jaywalker Measurable acceleration is also gained by not following a geodesic in flat spacetime.

Comment: @201044 Without accelerating relative to distant objects, you'd feel an acceleration. Without accelerating relative to your own frame is like freefall. Other observers would say you are accelerating

Comment: If the 'spaceship' is travelling at a constant speed of 1/2 c through a very curved space not along a geodesic would an observer on the ship 'notice' any measurable distortions?

Comment: Could a 'very' curved space alter the effects of some experiments that are carried out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the elements of a ruler are following geodesics, the distortion is governed by the Raychauduri equation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raychaudhuri_equation).

If the space is highly curved the result is stresses due to the expansion or contraction of the different parts of the ruler following slightly different geodesics.

Comment: So distortions to a ruler would be noticeable in the ship. But if the ship is traveling with uniform speed would this violate the principle of equivalence?